# Is Ubuntu or Linux OS more on coding?

Tags: programming

There is some problem when install this OS because I cant connect to wifi so i saw some tutorial about using nautilus keyword and works. I switch to use Ubuntu just now but is Ubuntu more on coding or programming?

Comment: GUI should be able to do most of what you want to do - just us nerds sometimes prefer it :) .  Relevant Q on meta: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/12246/wouldnt-it-be-better-to-help-users-without-sending-them-to-the-terminal

Answer (score 4):

The Linux culture is to have many tools that can do the same job.

Our system is strongly connected to server instances so we have situations where users do not have a desktop. We also have situation where servers are on a remote location.

For that reason we have a terminal where we can insert commands and have them execute. This can be a simple list of files in a folder (`ls`) to a editing text files to configure your graphics card.

The big plus with this: those commands also work for desktop users.

Often there is a graphical option to do it from the desktop but those are not uniform across all desktops (we have more versions that do not use Unity as a desktop) so it is easier for someone to post commands on-line for you to use in a terminal. Otherwise he would need to provide images on how to do something in Unity, in KDE or any other desktop.

---

Understanding those commands though should be a must for anyone using Ubuntu. So yes... we are more of a coding/programmers operating system. In that sense we are totally different from Windows. But it is NOT that difficult. Give it a couple of weeks and you will understand all the codes that you need.

There are commands that look innocent but can cause trouble though. When you find a piece of code that needs to be inserted into a terminal and you are unsure you can always ask in [Ubuntu Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) (20 reputation required).

All code in all the questions on AskUbuntu should be safe to use (if applicable) or it should have a big fat warning. Be careful when using destructive commands (like `rm` (remove) or `mv` (move) or when they are about formatting partitions and when commands need a password).

Comment: Wow! Great! I think in this operating system i will become a programmer and the best thing about this it works fine to my old model laptop. I will follow your instruction to become careful when using terminal commands by using rm or mv keyword. I think i will enjoy this OS and it is a great start for me. Thanks for your answer and i really appreciate it and get idea on how Linux based OS works.

Comment: @KerthG.: Don't thank Rinzwind!  **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu means humanity, so you can use ubuntu for coding, for high level network engineering, for programming, for design, for film editing, for games, for pentest, for everything you want.

### Install ubuntu, it's great :D

Do you want windows applications? install Wine or VirtualBox or VMware.

Comment: Hey dude! thanks for the idea that it can work for graphics. I just wanted to become graphics designer or web developer i don't think so if there are some softwares that i can install here like photoshop, sony vegas, or any other apps for graphics design. Do you have some applications that can i use for video editing?

Comment: @KerthG. you can install blender, gimp, inkspace, adobe programs for Wine, Openshot, Kdenlive, VLC media player(We know that VLC is not only a media player), shotwell image viewer is pre-installed, make human and many other apps, it has cool software center, that would help you, libre office, if you are a cool coder you can use python  for graphic designs, if you have questions ask me and remember, UBUNTU IS A GREAT CHOICE THAN MAC OR WINDOWS, most of Hollywood computers and servers are running ubuntu.

Comment: you know dude, i am not good in computer yet but according to your explanation if i master Ubuntu or linux base OS i have chance to work as administrator of computer in America? I wish to work there but my talent in computer is not good like the other i hope Ubuntu will help me to improve my skills and knowledge in computer. You're cool too because you know lot of things to this OS. I remember your name Zviad Gabrshvili :)

Comment: You are right @KerthG. I started from Windows scripts and I was completely noob in Computer, but now I can make cool programs and malware in Windows and Ubuntu, I started noob scripting when I was 10 years old, now I am 14 years old and help people to learn something new and teach programming, I love computer, but I hate gaming, it takes time and at last their computers are vulnerable against hackers to help such people I make a website, I will be glad if you visit: http://www.zneweasy.com

Comment: oh really, we're the same i hate playing games because i don't want to waste my time playing. ahaha. I just want to learn more stuffs in computer, you know dude im already 22 years old and i start learning computer from 2010 because internet here in our place are very slow. I gonna follow you to my facebook :) thanks to your help and information abut ubuntu it really helps me and caught my attention to improve my computing skills.

Comment: What's your facebook/twitter

Comment: i don't have twitter dude but i already saw your facebook page. I sent you a message. Nice to meet you

Comment: Thank you, it's easy to hack a gamer than a coder or programmer.

Comment: yeh i believe with you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is for everyone. Both the coder, the coding amatuer and the GUI user.

In most cases, what you need doing can be done just as well with a GUI rather than the terminal. In some situations, the terminal and a little coding will be needed - but there are a wealth of tutorials out there to provide you with help if you need it.

In short, Ubuntu is more on coding if you want it to be, just as Ubuntu is more on GUI if you want it.

After all, Ubuntu is Linux :D

Comment: wow! so it means this operating system is good background to become a programmer and developer? I think i will enjoy this operating according to your comment and those guys above :) Im happy that i switch to Ubuntu